# Trying to watch expanded/detailed view of a variable using Firebug

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firebug

I tried to inspect the value of a JS variable when debugging with Firefox, but only the first level of info can be seen from the Firebug console.

See the screen shot, below *(editor's note: screenshot not yet provided)*.

I have clicked the "+" and it has changed to "-", but I still can NOT watch the detailed info for this variable.

Comment: user844078, please post the screen shot that you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `console.dir()` instead of `console.log()`